# MySQL suggestions on DB design of N° values in 1 column or 1 column for value

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, performance

I need to move my local project to a webserver and it is time to start saving things locally (users progress and history).
The main idea is that the webapp every 50ms or so will calculate 8 values that are related to the user which is using the webapp.
My questions are:

1. Should i use MySQL to store the data? At the moment im using a plain text file with a predefined format like:

   ```
   Option1,Option2,Option3
   Iteration 1
   value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
   Iteration 2
   value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
   Iteration 3
   value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
   ...
   ```
2. If so, should i use 5 (or more in the future) columns (one for each value) and their ID as Iteration? Keep in mind i will have 5000+ Iterations per session (roughly 4mins)
3. Each users can have 10-20 sessions a day.
4. Will the DB become too big to be efficient?
5. Due to the sample speed a call to the DB every 50 ms seems a problem to me (especially since i have to animate the webpage heavily). I was wondering if it would be better to implement a Save button which populate all the DB with all the 5000+ values in one go. If so what could it be the best way?
6. Would it be better to save the *.txt directly in a folder in the webserver? Something like DB/usernameXYZ/dateZXY/filename_XZA.txt . To me yes, way less effort. If so which is the function that allows me to do so (possible JS/HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are simple, and are discussed in many Q&A here.

With rare exceptions...

- Do not have multiple tables with the same schema.  (Eg, one table per User)
- Do not splay an array across columns.  Use another table.
- Do not put an array into a single column as a commalist.  Exception:  If you never use SQL to look at the individual items in the list, then it is ok for it to be an opaque text field.
- Be wary of EAV schema.
- Do batch `INSERTs` or use `LOAD DATA`.  (10x speedup over one-row-per-INSERT)
- Properly indexed, a billion-row table performs just fine.  (Problem: It may not be possible to provide an adequate index.)
- Images (a la your .txt files) could be stored in the filesystem or in a `TEXT` column in the database -- there is no universal answer of which to do.  (That is, need more details to answer your question.)

"calculate 8 values that are related to the user" -- to vague.  Some possibilities:

- Dynamically computing a 'rank' is costly and time-consuming.
- Summary data is best pre-computed
- Huge numbers (eg, search hits) are best approximated
- Calculating age from birth date - trivial
- Data sitting in the table for that user is, of course, trivial to get
- Counting number of 'friends' - it depends
- etc.